# Google Chart Tools API in Phonegap application for Android?

Tags: cordova, google-visualization

I´d like to add charts in my phonegap application. I have tested phonegap wiht Google chart image in wich you pass a fat url with the proper parameters and it returs a png image with the chart and it woks fine.

Now I want to try with the google chart tools API because it offers more user interactivity. I have tested it in non-mobile web apps and it works, but when I try to use it in a phonegap project all I get is a black screen with this text: "Hello World, ChartsActivity!"

Does anyone have an example of how to integrate the google charts in a phonegap project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I´ve found the answer to my problem.

I discovered that Android (I´m working with version 2.2) has not yet SVG display support enabled. So the Google chart tools API and the Visualization API in general can´t be used as it relies on SVG format. It´s a shame. I hope soon this will be fixed.

Here is a link to the issue tracker where comments on the subject are posted: 
 [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376)

Comment: Did you find another way to display basic charts in your Android app ?

Comment: @Hubert, Not yet if we are talking about vector based charts. The only easy way of display charts I´ve found is using the Google image charts wich return a PNG image of the chart in response of a formated URL invokation. You can check this [link](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/chart/image/) for an example